# GetBytes Issue in Loading External Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, preloader

I'm trying to debug a gallery section within a site of mine. Currently the section display a number of thumbnails which visitor select one to view.

Once selected, the main flash loads in an external swf. To make the process smoother, I have a preloader for this process using normal getbytes codes. However for some reasons, the flash works fine in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome.

In these browsers, as soon as you click the thumbnail, the preloader animated away to reveal the holder of the external swf. However as it is still loading, the holder is a blank area.

Would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on why this is so.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct event for the preloader's transitionOut. The event flow, for progressive SWFs (SWFs with more than one frame at its MainTimeline, so they would eventually start playing before being completely loaded), is like this:

```
open (onLoadStart in AS2)
progress (onLoadProgress in AS2)
progress
...
init (onLoadInit in AS2)
progress
progress
...
complete (onLoadComplete in AS2)
```

"init" is triggered when the first frame of the SWF is executed (along with all his code). "complete" is triggered when the download of the file ends.

Cheers...